# Sync many small files with msdeploy busts the ci machine

Tags: powershell, iis, deployment, teamcity, msdeploy

I am moving 30000 files (1,8GB) from a networkshare to another remote computer`s iis virtual path.

The build machine`s memory (8GB max) consumption grows from 3.6 GB to 7,8 GB ... and everything on the CI machine is freezed.

How can I improve that process?

What could be bottlenecks?

Is msdeploy the right tool to sync files on a remote pc?

```
echo "start copy process"
$path = "C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe";
$verb = "-verb:sync";
$src = "-source:contentPath=`"$sourcePath`"";

$dest = "-dest:contentPath=%TargetIISPath%,computerName=%TargetComputerName%,username=%NTUserName%,password=%NTUserPassword%";
echo $dest
Invoke-Expression "&'$path' --% $verb $src $dest -verbose";
```

Comment: Robocopy as it was designed for this purpose.

Comment: You can zip files in source and unzip in target for first sync and for keeping in sync use as answered robocopy.
Robocopy even supports a monitor-function for subsequent copies.

Comment: I found out, that an IIS site was responsible for the memory rise. The sync is just freezing the computer because of the heavy I/O on the disc.

Answer (score 0):

MSDeploy was definitely designed for this purpose.  I've never personally tried to sync a site this big but would be surprised if it wasn't supported.

Could you temporarily stop the other site that is using all the resources?  Or deploy during a down time?

Comment: Its syncing 30000 pdf files blob files for the service ;-) We ordered a new machine now extra for this application. When I have too much time, I still try robocopy then!